# String.Format - integer, thousands separator, no decimal

Tags: .net, string.format

what is the simplest String.Format template to format an integer with a thousands separator (comma) and no decimal places? en-US culture. Examples of desired formatting:

```
1200 = 1,200

900 = 900

8 = 8
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N0 is the format you are looking for.
N will format it with commas, and the 0 is to tell it to not use decimals:

```
// will format as 33,540
string.Format("{0:N0}", 33540.54M)

// example using an integer: 1,200
string.Format("{0:N0}", 1200);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Result: Integral and decimal digits, group separators, and a decimal
>   separator with optional negative sign. Supported by: All numeric
>   types. Precision specifier: Desired number of decimal places. Default
>   precision specifier: Defined byNumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits.
>   More information: The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible to do using only a format string. You also have to specify the culture or number format, or make sure that the current culture is the right one. The thousands separator uses the separator specified in the culture, you can't specify the separator in the format.

The format string `N0` is the shortest to get thousands separator and zero decimal places.

Example:

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N0}", 12345678.901234)
```

Comment: it's not necessary to cite the culture when using a string.Format template, like so:

`string.Format("There are <b>{0:#,0}</b> results matching your query:", resultsCount);`

...and as i indicated, im using the en-US culture.

Comment: also, you certainly can specify the thousands separator to a symbol of your choosing, like so: `{0:#|0}` yields "1|200"

Comment: @mdelvecchio: It's unclear from the question if you are specifically using the en-US culture, or if you want the result formatted according to the en-US culture. I just wanted to make clear in the answer that you have to make sure that you use a specific culture to get the right thousands separator. It's only the `,` that means the thousands separator in the format, the format `{0:#|0}` doesn't yield `1|200` but `120|0`.

Comment: I specified in my question that en-US is the target. also, you're mistaken -- {0:#|0} does indeed yield "1|200" when using en-US (my server's default culture). I tried it myself and you should do the same....so yes, you can specify the separator used in a string.Format, just not with your suggested answer. fortunately for me I don't need anything other than a comma.

Comment: @mdelvecchio: The question only mentioned a culture, so it's not clear what that means, so I wanted to be very clear in the answer. I already tried using the format `{0:#|0}` in a format string and specifying the en-US culture, and I even tried it again now to be absolutely sure, and the result is just as I wrote before. Using `|` in a format string has no special meaning, so it's just inserted at that place in the string. See [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: which is exactly what i said -- you *can* specify any symbol to use for the thousands separator using a string.Format template. you: "The thousands separator uses the separator specified in the culture, you can't specify the separator in the format." me: "you certainly can specify the thousands separator to a symbol of your choosing, like so: {0:#|0}". you were mistaken, and it's ok. the citing of the culture in my question is obviously informing which culture is being used by the string.Format. what else could it mean?

Comment: @mdelvecchio: No, that't not what you said. You can specify any character you want to include in the format, but you can't specify it as thousands separator. The format `{0:#|0}` inserts the `|` before the last digit in the number, not as thousands separator. Regarding the culture, only mentioning it can mean either that the culture is specified, or that the format string should give the same result as formatting with that culture.

Answer (score 0):

i found one that works as expected:

```
{0:#,0}
```